# Printing class names from wrapper

Tags: java

I have an array holding different data structures, all of which `implement` the same `interface`:

```
    dataStructures = new SimpleSet[]{new OpenHash(), new CloseHash(),
            new someClass(new TreeSet<>()), new someClass(new HashSet<>()),
            new someClass(new LinkedList<>());
```

Now I want to print all `dataStructures` names?

For the first two I used while iterating over the array `getClass().getName()` and it worked; however, for the rest, which are wrapped by `someClass`, this would not work. Is there any way that I could print the them by name like `TreeSet` `HashSet` `LinkedList`?

Comment: Show us a structure of SomeClass. You should access to a field that is initialized with constructor parameter and perform the same action getClass().getName().

Comment: If you have getter for the `TreeSet`, etc. in your `someClass`, you can get the `TreeSet` by the getter method through the index and then call the class method, i.e.: `dataStructures[1].getTreeSet().getClass().getName();`

Comment: @sphinks thanks alot that solved it